# Root certificate invalid on a WHM site

Tags: ssl, https, certificate-authority

I am a newbie in SSL certificates and was given the task on troubleshooting a site's WHM page that uses https but it displays an red "x" on the https section of the URL.

On Google Chrome, details of the error says:

```
Root certificate authority
Expires: Tuesday, May 5, 2015
```

then down below it says:

```
This root certificate is not trusted
```

On Firefox, details of the error says:

```
<sitename> uses an invalid security certificate. 
The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed. 
(Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)
```

What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Buy a certificate signed by a trusted CA and install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install Service SSL Certificates in WHM, you're showing the users of your server that you are who you say you are. When you use self-signed certificates, there's no authority that attests to the correctness of the certificate's information. This causes a trust warning in the browser, telling users that they may not be dealing with whom they wish.

More information can be found about self-signed certs here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate

There are many CA's (Certificate Authorities) who can provide SSL certs at a reasonable price. Shop around and find one that satisfies your needs. Comodo is an example of a CA that offers bargain pricing on their basic certs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know know that self signed certs is not that secure and third party CA is much better.